# PoshRSJob on Remote Computers

Tags: powershell

I'm attemting to use PoshRSJob to run jobs on remote computers, however it looks like what I've currently got is only running `$JobFilePath` locally instead of the remote targets from `$AuditTargetsFile`. From my understanding, the code below *should* be doing the remoting, however it's not. Any ideas how I can fix this?

```
$JobFilePath = "path\to\Job.ps1"
$AuditTargetsFile "path\to\targets\AuditTargets.txt"

$Targets = Get-Content $AuditTargetsFile -ErrorAction Stop | & { Process { If ($_.Trim() -ne"") {$_.Trim()}}} | Sort-Object | Get-Unique

$Targets | Start-RSJob -Name {$_} -Batch "AuditJob" -FilePath $JobFilePath -Throttle 16 -ThreadOptions UseNewThread | Out-Null
```

Comment: Why not use `Invoke-Command` ?